# python pandas - aggregate and keep other columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

i am trying to group my csv dataset together by the variables time_start and time_end with pandas depending on the time between interactions (in this case, >20 seconds).

However, when i apply my groupby, and aggregate, my result is a dataframe with only the variables time_start, time_end and total_time. Now i cannot know which tag_me or tag_them had these connections. what am i doing wrong here?

original dataset:

```
tag_me,tag_them,time_remote_s,rssi,angle,group,time_start,time_end,total_time
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,932,-94,14,1,1356,1363,7
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,167,-87,13,1,1364,1364,0
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,941,-84,7,1,1365,1366,1
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,169,-90,4,1,1366,1366,0
0x597E5627,0x36570942,906,-94,4,1,1366,1366,0
0x597E5627,0x3C3A21AD,728,-90,8,1,1369,1369,0
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,155,-87,7,1,1370,1374,4
0x597E5627,0x064F5882,313,-83,6,1,1379,1379,0
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,166,-94,10,1,1381,1381,0
0x597E5627,0x064F5882,316,-94,8,1,1381,1382,1
0x597E5627,0x36570942,923,-94,7,1,1383,1390,7
```

my algorithm that looks at the start and end times of each row:

```
df = df.groupby(((df.time_start  - df.time_end.shift(1)) < 20).cumsum()).agg({'time_start':min, 'time_end':max, 'total_time':sum})
```

my result:

```
time_start, time_end, total_time
0, 1356, 1404, 22
1, 1427, 1427, 0
2, 1463, 1463, 0
3, 1502, 1727, 115
4, 1755, 2506, 737
5, 2540, 2596, 17
6, 2628, 2681, 33
```

I lost all the info about the name of the tag_me and tag_them. My desired result is still containing all the other columns. I want to merge each row of tag_me and tag_them that are the same id's and that are in a window of 20 seconds of each other.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you want a column you need to specify it in `agg()`.  How else would Pandas know whether to use the first/last/min/max/mean/etc value?

Comment: Are you parsing data from csv file? Can you display your dataframe structure to reproduce also will be great if you show the desired output.

Comment: @pygo yes sorry, i am indeed parsing from a csv file. the structure is shown in the original dataset part of my question. the df is 15249 rows x 9 columns

Comment: @JohnZwinck i understand that i have to specifiy it in the agg() part. however, these are strings and i can only give pandas instructions like min, max, mean.

Comment: @intStdu , you can remove commas while processing csv with pandas and then segregate your column at the time of processing only to get desired columns and henceforth do the data parsing whatever you want that way it will go faster and will read only desired columns... If I you link your csv data somewhere then will be easy to reproduce it...

Comment: Desired output please?

Comment: @intStdu: You can use other agg types like `'first'` and `'last'` with strings.